# BLE 113 Blue giga Converting .bgs to .hex

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I bought a bluetooth module 4.0 off blue giga and 
I am trying to write a program for it.
I just figured out that you can edit the .bgs file with
notepad so I am writing a program through notepad (i know there
has to be a better way but I haven't found a way), but I was
wondering if anyone knew how to convert the .bgs file to .hex
since the module only takes .hex files. I understand there are
programs that convert .c to .hex but haven't found one for .bgs.
Any help would be great. I've been doing research and people are saying
the tool converts it for me but I didn't know what tool

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the SDK from Bluegiga support pages:
https://bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble113-bluetooth--smart-module/documentation/

I recommend you to read the getting started guide which is at the same web page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the "BGScript compiler" which is part of the "Bluetooth Smart SDK" provided by bluegiga.  I'm not sure where you get it, but it may come packaged with their hardware.